# finding the multiples of 2 numbers in an array using .forEach() in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I'm required to loop through an array using the .forEach method, returning all the values and if any of the numbers are a multiple of 3 or 5 and then also both 3 & 5, that number must be returned as a string. My code thus far:

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
14, 15];
let count = [];
arr.forEach((item) => {
count[item] = item;
if (count[item] % 3 === 0) {
count[item] = "Fizz";
  } else if (count[item] % 5 === 0) {
    count[item] = "Buzz";
  } else if (count[item] % 3 === 0 || count[item] % 5 === 0) {
    count[item] = "FizzBuzz";}
  return count;});
console.log(count);
```

The issue I'm having is that I'm unable to get it to return the final string of "FizzBuzz" & also omit the initialization of the count variable from displaying in the console.

I'm a total beginner with JS so if you could provide an explanation of the answer where applicable I will appreciate it.

Images of outputs below:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBnyK.jpg)

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdwkn.png)

Edit:

I forgot to mention that it's an exercise which is part of an assignment so I'm required to use the forEach method, which also makes it different to the other other question linked to, in that a for loop was used there.

Comment: You need `&&` to check for both, `||` is an OR check. You also cannot use if / else if / else if in that order because if one test checks out, the others are skipped. You need to move the most specific test up.

Comment: You need to check for `FizzBuzz` first. Otherwise, the `Fizz` check will be true and it will never get to the `FizzBuzz`  check

Comment: As far as the IF statements go it does answer my question, thanks  @sm3sher. I should have tried searching for FizzBuzz lol. though I am required to use the forEach method to check the elements in the array I'm sure I could have figured it out had I found it. Thank you

Comment: Okay, I actually have been checking with && and only changed it around to see if it would work, thanks for pointing that out though @chrisG, I have changed it now. Thank you

Comment: @Barmar, thank you for pointing that out, I've moved it up and am getting the FizzBuzz output now. thank you for your help.

Comment: Here's a one-line version: https://jsfiddle.net/wv49x5hp/

Comment: That's an Amazing piece of code @chrisG, though my beginner brain cannot comprehend what I'm looking it as yet lol.  My answer needs to be with using forEach though, It's a class assignment exercise, Sorry I should have mentioned that in my post.

Comment: The number `n` gets turned into `(A + B) || n` where A and B are ternary expressions: `condition ? result_if_true : result_if_false`. If A, B or both result in the word, the word is returned, n if not.

Comment: Thank you very much. 
Very well explained Chris, I understand now :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I used guard clauses to make the whole if statement stuff a little more clean
- you can use Array.forEach() with the index as argument, which is quite helpful here

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
  14, 15];

arr.forEach(function(element, index) {
  if (element % 5 === 0 && element % 3 === 0) return arr[index] = "Fizz-Buzz"
  if (element % 5 === 0) return arr[index] = "Buzz"
  if (element % 3 === 0) return arr[index] = "Fizz"
})

console.log(arr)
```

also be aware, that javascript arrays start with the index 0 ... so `count[item] = [item]` leaves an undefined spot at count[0] ... you should rather have your forEach function make use of the index argument, that can be passed to it (in your particular case using count[item] = [item] doesn't create that many problems) but better do it the right way from the start

here the code without guard clauses:

```js
arr.forEach(function (element, index) {
  if (element % 5 === 0 && element % 3 === 0) {
    arr[index] = "Fizz-Buzz"
  } else if (element % 5 === 0) {
    arr[index] = "Buzz"
  } else if (element % 3 === 0) {
    arr[index] = "Fizz"
  }
})
```

Comment: I'm amazed at all the different variations of code to get the same result, your code works perfectly even though I do not quite understand what I'm looking at as yet but I will definitely do more research on the guard clauses. I think I will go with this answer for the exercise as it's pretty much what I was trying to achieve with my code, just more clean as you stated lol. thank you very much @Lord-JulianXLII

Comment: @RiyaazSingh you can look at the guard clauses as else-ifs
Basically it goes like this: Check if element is divisible by 5 AND 3 if true return (exit function) and set current index to FizzBuzz - if false procced to next if clause - if element then is divisible by 5 return (exit function) and set current index to Buzz - if false proceed to next if clause ... and so on

Comment: @RiyaazSingh added the code with the guard clauses converted to "normal" if else-if syntax - you should be able to see what the guard clauses do more easily now

Comment: Thank you so much, I've read both your comment here now as well as the reply & I do understand what you're saying, using the indexes looked a bit scary to me when I was looking up solutions lol but I will study your code and apply it.

Comment: Excellent explanation on the guard clause @Lord-JulianXLII, I don't think I need to look elsewhere for clarification, very well explained. thank you. I actually understand the IF statement a whole lot better as well now.

Answer (score 0):

You needed to check "FizBuzz" first and then "Fizz" and "Buzz" seperately.
In this case I would prefer to use **.map** instead of **.forEach** in this case, because **.map** returns each element, so you don't need to create a new empty array.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

const res = arr.map(el => {
    if(el % 3 === 0 && el % 5 === 0)
        return "FizBuzz"
    else if (el % 3 === 0)
        return "Fizz"
    else if (el % 5 === 0)
        return "Buzz"
    else return el
})

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to mention that it's actually an exercise for an assignment and we're required to use either forEach or both forEach & map. though i tried it on my own with map & forEach but failed miserably. The answer I arrived at was from taking bits from different results I found online and trying to make it work. been at this since Saturday afternoon already and my head hurts. lol

Comment: I'm happy to see how it could be done using Map as well though and will definitely study your method. thank you @Stūrainis